# Add button in commandbar when opening a workbook, remove it when closed, and make available for all open workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I wish for the following to work but can not seem to get it right.

when the workbook opens it removes first what it wants to add.
then it will add a bar, menu and button when needed for all the open workbooks. 
this works fine for the first opened file but when a second workbook is opened the macro from the first workbook will not be available in the second macro.

*addition : the custom addin bar should be constant a button should be added on open and removed on close. The whole bar should be created when created when not availabe and removed if the last button is removed.*

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

    BarExsists = False
    MenuExsists = False

    For Each Wndw In Application.Windows
    'remove exsisting menubar
    For Each Bar In Application.CommandBars
        If Bar.Name = BarName Then
            BarExsists = True
            If Not IsEmpty(Application.CommandBars(BarName).Controls(MenuName)) Then
                MenuExsists = True
                For Each Menu In Bar.Controls
                    'remove control
                    For Each Button In Menu.Controls
                        If Button.Caption = ButtonName Then
                            Button.Delete
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next Button
                    'remove menu when last control removed
                    If Menu.Controls.Count = 0 Then
                        Menu.Delete
                        MenuExsists = False
                        Bar.Delete
                        BarExsists = False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next Menu
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Bar

    If BarExsists Then
        Set Bar = Application.CommandBars(BarName)
    Else
        Set Bar = Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=BarName, Position:=1)
    End If

    Bar.Visible = True

    If MenuExsists Then
        Set Menu = Bar.Controls(MenuName)
    Else
        Set Menu = Bar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=1)
        With Menu
            .Caption = MenuName
        End With
    End If

    With Menu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=2949)
        .Caption = ButtonName
        .OnAction = ButtonAction
        .TooltipText = ButtonToolTip
        .FaceId = 600
    End With
Next Wndw

End Sub
```

workbook_open from the first workbook should be run again! but something like the following does not work. Each different approach of the Application.Run - command results either in a 1004 or a 438 error. I can not find the reason and the only option available according to google and SOF tells me to use the run - command also tried to resolve the string first like:

```
wbMacro = "'" & wb.Path & "\" & wb.Name & "'!Workbook_Open"

For Each wb In Workbooks 'note still have to add check if exsist before running it
    Application.Run "'" & wb.Path & "\" & wb.Name & "'!Workbook_Open"
    'Application.Run wbMacro
Next wb
```

thanks in advance for any response,

Comment: *`... and make available for all open workbooks`* - that AFAIK is not possible.

Comment: the custom addin menu structure must not change when switching workbooks. I will change/add this to the question.

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is an XLAM add-in file.